# Вместо страницы сайта yii2 на ubuntu 16.04 отображается текст, как исправить?

Tags: ubuntu, yii2, nginx

По данному видео устанавливал сайт yii2 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khpMJiZDvkE. 
Если в настройках nginx root /var/www/yii/crm_2/3/backend/web; то выйдет стандартная страница yii
[image: backend]
Если ссылаться на сайт где основной проект root /var/www/yii/crm_2.3/frontend/web;
То выходит следующее [image: frontend]
В чем может быть проблема?

Настраиваем конфигурацию nginx:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

Меняем содержимое на:
!!!Меняем путь в root


server{
 charset utf-8;
 client_max_body_size 128M;

 listen 80;

 server_name backend.dev;
 #root /var/www/yii/project/backend/web;
 root /var/www/yii/crm_2.3/frontend/web;
 #root /var/www/yii/crm_2.3/backend/web;
 index index.php;

 access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

 location / {
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

 include /etc/nginx/php.conf;

 location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
 access_log off;
 log_not_found off;
 expires off;
}

 location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
 access_log off;
 log_not_found off;
 deny all;
 }
}


Создаем файл /etc/nginx/php.conf:
sudo touch /etc/nginx/php.conf

Добавляем в него содержимое:

sudo nano/etc/nginx/php.conf


location ~ \.php$ {
 include fastcgi_params;
 #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
 fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
 #fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php5-fpm.sock;
 fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;


 fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
 fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
 fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
}
```

php установлен [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если в index.php прописать `<?php 
echo 'hello, nginx!!!! lol';
echo phpinfo();
?>`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
frontend/config/main.php

```
<?
use \kartik\datecontrol\Module;
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
    'modules' => [
        'gridview' =>  ['class' => '\kartik\grid\Module'],
        'datecontrol' => [
            'class' => '\kartik\datecontrol\Module',
            'displaySettings' => [
                Module::FORMAT_DATE => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                Module::FORMAT_TIME => 'hh:mm:ss a',
                Module::FORMAT_DATETIME => 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a',
            ],
            'saveSettings' => [
                Module::FORMAT_DATE => 'php:U', // saves as unix timestamp
                Module::FORMAT_TIME => 'php:H:i:s',
                Module::FORMAT_DATETIME => 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s',
            ],
        ],

    ],
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
    ],
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-frontend', 'httpOnly' => true],
    ],
    'session' => [
        // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the frontend
        'name' => 'advanced-frontend',
    ],
    'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'bot' => [
        'class' => 'frontend\components\TelegramComponent',
        'apiToken' => '411890271:AAGOEkFv8aZSMnNNMK2qmKG5X94Cr4JtxS8',
    ],
    'errorHandler' => [
        'errorAction' => 'site/error',
    ],
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
         'rules' => [
            'admin' => 'zakaz/admin',
            'view/<id:\d+>' => 'zakaz/view',
            'disain' => 'zakaz/disain',
            'master' => 'zakaz/master',
            'shop' => 'zakaz/shop',
            'courier' => 'courier/index',
            'todoist' => 'todoist/index',
            'helpdesk' => 'helpdesk/index',
            'custom' => 'custom/index',
            'versia' => 'zakaz/index',
            'create' => 'zakaz/create',
            'update/<id:\d+>' => 'zakaz/update',
            'login' => 'site/login',
            'logout' => 'site/logout',
            'createzakaz/<id_zakaz:\d+>' => 'todoist/createzakaz',
            'view-todoist/<id:\d+>' => 'todoist/view',

        ],
    ],
],
'params' => $params,
```

];

Comment: у вас php точно работает? А то такое ощущение что текст файлов тупо вываливается в веб

Comment: @ArchDemon В диспетчер пакетов php есть. Скриншот приведу в описании. php init тоже стоит, проект клонировал с гит, потом компоузером недостающие элементы ставил через compouser install.

Comment: тогда остаётся смотреть логи ошибок

Comment: @ArchDemon Есть вариант что конфиг nginx неправильный ? И где смотреть логи?) Я новичок в этом.

Comment: А файл `frontend/config/main.php` не меняли?

Comment: @pa3py6aka В основной теле написал как он выглядит. Да менял т.к там прописаны пути.

Comment: В итоге я поставил apache2 настроил , сайт запустился, в какой то момент такая же ошибка вышла ,что вместо сайта отображается только текст, в самом etc/php/php5.6/apache2 в конфи я до этого клал файл php.ini чтобы увеличить объем загружаемого файла бд для phpmyadmin. Я подумал может дело в файле php.ini который я в конфиг положил ,удалил его и сайт опять начал работать нормально. ( основной файл php.ini который лежит в папке cli при изменение объема данных для загрузки файлов в phpmyadmin не реагировал) Я где то еще ковырялся в итоге когда я отключил апач , сайт уже работал на nginx ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалось адресно решить такую же проблему, без полной замены конфигов.
У меня дело было в параметре "short_open_tag".  Когда он "off", код идущий после "<?" не воспринимается как php и не интерпретируется, потому что не "<?php". 
А как раз в конфиге встречалось "<?" и всё разваливалось)

Comment: Скорее всего у ТС была именно такая проблема, но теперь уже поздно ему помогать.

Comment: Total Pusher, а я написал для следующего, кто будет искать решение этой проблемы, как я недавно искал - и не нашёл, сам ковырял. 
ТС-то, понятное дело, справился уже давно, о чём и отписался.

Answer (score 0):

Для apache2 я воспроизвел данную проблему, если в /etc/php/5.6/apache2 добавить файл php.ini и в /etc/php/5.6/cli лежит php.ini (который там был при установке). То всплывает данная ошибка. 
В nginx такая проблема была из за того ,что при клонирование репозитория и установки php.ini в проект, он заменял все конфигурационный файлы в папке config в проекте yii2 (скорее всего я невнимательно ставил т.к в процессе установки он спрашивает стоит ли заменить файлы), после правки файлов config сайт и на nginx стал работать нормально.